# need help in using bitbake INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE flag

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am new to bitbake. and I have multiple questions all related to each other.

1. I am trying to remove all the packages that are GPLv3 from my package. i see that there are .bb files for both versions (gplv2 and gplv3 or other license types as applicable), of packages in meta/recipes-*/ folders. If I use INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE=GPLv3 it removes all the packages that are GPLv3. But I want to include some packages that are GPLv3. where do i specify this.
   I do see a BBFILES flag in the bblayers.conf in poky/build/conf dir. is this this place to add the specific recipes?
2. Another question i have is, If i want to use a specific .bb file out of the multiple .bb files in the recipes-*/* folder how do i do that. for example

/recipes-extended/tar/tar_1.17.bb
                     /tar_1.27.1.bb

In this case, how do i pick tar_1.17.bb and ignore 1.27.bb. This is just one example. There is a "bitbake -b" command that takes .bb file as input but that will build only that .bb file and ignore dependencies according to the documentation. I want to build the complete package and be able to pick and ignore a specific .bb file.

3. So, how does bitbake pick and more pricisely which .bb file does bitbake pick when there are multiple .bb files in the recipe folder.

Answer (score 3):

1 There's no way to do that. What would the purpose be? Normally, if you want to avoid GPLv3, you want a completely GPLv3 free image

There's one way to circumvent the system. You can set 

`INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE_pn-<package/recipe name> = ""`

That will allow you to build the package. However, don't use this for production, unless you really know what you're doing.

2/3: Normally the highest version will be built. You can use 

`PREFERRED_VERSION_<package name>`

in local.conf or in your distro, to select another version. Another way is to add 

`DEFAULT_PREFERENCE = "-1"`

to the recipe you don't want to build.

Comment: thanks. PREFERRED_VERSION_<package name> is what I was looking for. I can eliminate most of GPLv3 packages and build GPLv2 in their place with this addition to my local.conf file

Comment: don't understand this syntax, do I do INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE_gcc = "GPL-3.0-with-GCC-exception"
?

Comment: "What would the purpose be?"  To include a package temporarily during development and debugging, but not production (for example `bootchart2`).  I found I had to circumvent it in the `local.conf` file, which helps prevent these changes from making it into production.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set

```
WHITELIST_<spdx_license> += "<name of the package which you want to white list>"
```

Not very well documented but the code is in poky/meta/base.bbclass